# Steps to find optimal transformation for wide-sense stationarity

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, stationarity

I've been trying to automate the procedure of choosing the best transformation for a non-stationary process (in R). For lack of a better term, "best transformation" here refers to the quality of forecastability yielded by different transformations with the optimal ARIMA model fitted on the same series.

I have implemented my own algorithm which combines several degrees of differencing for constant mean and log-transformation for constant variance. The choice of lag constant is automated with the heuristic used in package 'tseries' (I regressed it as a function of the length of the series using the output of adf.test). Using my own Augmented Dickey Fuller test function, I'm fitting an AR(1) model for every possible transformation setup, such as:

- 1st degree differencing without log-transformation model
- 2nd degree differencing without log-transformation model
- 1st degree differencing with log-transformation model
- 2nd degree differencing with log-transformation model
- etc.

My "smart" algorithm looks at all ADF objects (one per transformation), rejects all transformations/models which do not have a unit root, and is then faced with the dilemma of finding the *best* stationary model (if such a thing exists). As a heuristic decision, I have set it to select the transformation whose ADF model diagnostics yields the maximum adjusted R-squared value. I'm not sure if this is a good approach because the algorithm tends to favour the most complex transformations, such as 3rd-4th degree integrated term without logarithmising for a series where I know for a fact that 1st degree differencing and log-transformation would suffice for a decent forecast. It would be too computationally expensive to choose the best transformation based on the *a posteriori* forecast performance so I would like to ask whether there is a standard approach to this problem (given that my approach is probably suboptimal).

NB: I'm not looking for an automated tool for the job, though if one exists I'd like to know what steps it takes to do it. I know that I could use *ndiffs* to determine the optimal degree of differencing but I'm not sure how to combine this output with potential log-transformations. If there's something to it that I'm missing, I would like to find out.

Comment: Have you considered using the Akaike information criterion over your parameter complexity and evaluation criteria?

Comment: This is not quite what I want; AIC is a useful metric for choosing an ARMA model (automated in auto.arima) but my question is actually on the step before model selection (stationarity transformation). On this subject, auto.arima works well but doesn't consider log-transformations.

Comment: The idea is to treat the additional parameters of the transformation as additional AIC complexity.

Comment: I believe that AIC would favour the log transformation over everything else because of the reduction in variance. Also, it would mean that I'd have to evaluate a transformation only after fitting an ARMA model, which in my scenario would be a very expensive solution I'm afraid.